# gitlab ci trying to connect back to git

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

there is nothing more important to me than ensuring there's no human action involved in the CI process - ie you check into a branch, the ci wakes up, catches up from the main branch, tests, and if everything works fine - it pushes back into the main branch - if anything goes wrong, you just get an email and fix it.

I've been trying to implement this with gitlab ci and windows - but I just can't get it working.   I looked at the merge request stuff, but it really wants a human to create a merge request, which defeats the whole point - also it doesn't do the merge from main -> the feature branch which is important to me.

So - I've gotten to this point, which seems to work:

```bash
host_name=xxxxxxx
project=xxxxxx
key_file_location=xxxx
branch=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add $key_file_location
git remote set-url origin git@$host_name:$project.git

echo checking out $branch
git checkout $branch
git status
```

The status even says how I'm going in relationship to the remote branch, so it *feels* like something worked.   however - then I then run this command:

```bash
git pull origin main
```

and it hangs - and when I say hangs - it really just goes away and never comes back - I need to log into the windows box where the gitlab runner is running and issue *all* of the following to make the runner start working again

```bash
taskkill /im:git.exe /f
takskill /im:ssh.exe /f
taskkill /im:wish.exe /f
```

I thought it might be hanging on the "known_hosts" question - so I added the following lines:

```bash
ip=`nslookup $host_name 2>&1 | grep Address: | cut -d: -f 2 | sed 's/ //g'`
set +e
ssh-keygen -R $host_name
ssh-keygen -R $host_name
ssh-keygen -R $host_name,$ip
ssh-keyscan -H $host_name,$ip >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H $ip >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H $host_name >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
set -e
```

which achieved exactly nothing.

my runner is running on windows - using the bash shell from git\usr\bin.  I am a maintainer of my project, but I'm NOT an administrator on gitlab.

Can anyone tell me either:

- how to get what I'm doing working
- another way to merge between branches as part of the gitlab ci
- another way to do achieve what i want?

Comment: So basically you want to have each and every commit to a dev branch merged into main automatically?

Comment: yes exactly  - well, with the caveat that they have to pass our (very extended) testing first

Comment: Any reason you're not following the "(multiple) commits to dev branch → create MR → auto merge to `main` after pipeline (i.e. tests) succeeds" approach?

Comment: yes - I believe very much in ci (as opposed to feature branches) - https://martinfowler.com/articles/branching-patterns.html#ComparingFeatureBranchingAndContinuousIntegration - ie communication happens through code, and every dev is expected to submit a fully finished task _at least_ once or twice a day.  Just means smaller tasks.

Answer (score 0):

ok - I got it working by embedding a personal access token as a secret, and pushing back to a http address - but it's a horrible hack :(